# pytype returns bad-concrete-type for (apparently) valid classmethod

Tags: python, class-method, pytype

The following code fails to typecheck with PyType:

```
def Thing:
  _things = []  # type: List['Thing']
  @classmethod
  def get(cls, id_: int) -> Container['Thing']:
    return Container(cls._things[id_])
```

with the following error on the `get` line:

```
 Invalid instantiation of generic class [bad-concrete-type]
 Expected: Any
 Actually passed: Any
```

I have added a complete MWE in https://gist.github.com/brunokim/e86367ed63cbd52d96b3564f502831b2. Am I missing something to properly annotate the class attribute `things`? I notice on the pyi file that it's no different from instance attributes.